# PHP $_SESSION not getting set

Tags: php, hosting, fbconnect

I am trying learn integrating fb connect with a website. There I am facing some issue as follows.

After submitting the facebook information from (http://www.mydomain.com/exp/login.php) I am calling, process_data.php in the redirect uri like this,

```
<fb:registration fields="[
{'name':'name'},
{'name':'email'},
{'name':'who', 'description':'additional info',     'type':'text'}]"
redirect-uri="http://www.mydomain.com/exp/process_data.php"
</fb:registration>
```

Then, in the process_data.php, I do the following,

```
if ($_REQUEST) {
$response = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'], 
                               $appSect);

if($response){  
    $_SESSION['facebook_data'] = $response;
    header('Location: '.$redirect_url); //http://www.mydomain.com/exp/home.php
} else {
echo '$_REQUEST is empty';
}
```

and Finally, in the home.php,

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_data'])){
    //do something with data
  {
```

?>

but it never hits this code in home.php.

Is there anything to do with the hosting? or am I am doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Kasun

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` in your `process_data.php` page?

Comment: is `$redirect_url` set?

Comment: @danielrsmith: Yes, I do!

Comment: @verbumSapienti: yes, even re-directs to it but the session variable does not set properly.

Answer (score 0):

When you're redirecting, try doing:

```
 header("Location: newpage.php?PHPSESSID=".session­_id());
```

And then:

```
session_id($_GET['PHPSESSID']); 
session_start();
```

AFAIK the problem arises when you set a session variable and then redirect immediately, which not always works.

Note that it is better to store the session id in a cookie rather than in the URL.

Alternatively try using `exit` right after the redirect:

```
header("Location: newpage.php");
exit;
```

Comment: There is no alternatively, you should ALWAYS `exit;` the script after `header('Location: ...');`

Comment: Not always, you are allowed to do something after using `header()` but you cannot output anything.

Comment: @MMM : Still the same, I tried both ways. first one gives 500 error but nothing getting logged in my errorlog file. second, trying to exit just after redirect, does not hit the condition($_SESSION still not getting value)

Comment: If it gives you a 500 error then there must be some problem with the code, the concept itself should work...

Comment: <?php
      session_start();
      if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_data']))
     {

            $userid = $_SESSION['facebook_data']["user_id"];
            $fullname = $_SESSION['facebook_data']["registration"]  ["name"];
            
            $facebookData = array('Facebook User   ID'=>$userid,'Name'=>$fullname);
            
            
    }  
    else {
     echo 'ELSE';
    }
    ?> this is my file.

Comment: I am still thinking is there anything to do with my hosting provider? Any settling to be done?

Comment: I changed php version in my hosting account using cpanel to 5.5 from native (to be frank,I do not know what is native). After that my original code worked. Anyway thanks everyone for helping out. I learnt few new things from your answers as a newbie to php.